# jQuery - attribute value undefined

Tags: jquery, selenium-rc

Html code of an svg element :

```
<image xlink:href="start.gif" style="pointer-events:none" x="165" y="175" width="100" height="100" stroke-width="1" transform=" scale(1 1) translate(0 0)"/>
```

Just as a POC,

```
$('image').attr('xlink:href');
```

does return the attribute value as `start.gif`.

Now I need the attribute values of all the image elements, so I wrote a function

```
function script()
{
    var result = new Array();
    var elements = selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery('image');
    for(var i = 0 ; i < elements.length ; i++)
    {
        result[i] = $(this).attr('xlink:href');
    }
    return result;
}
script();
```

but this returns `undefined`

Why is that happening?

And yeah, I did try using jQuery's $.each(function(key, value)), but selenium throws "Error: Threw an exception : c.call is not a function". Didn't understand what c and call refers to, so thought to use js for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
result[i] = $(elements[i]).attr('xlink:href');
```

Comment: Thanks! As always, solved questions look stupid to me! Maybe I should delete this question?

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `.each` and try with `$(this)`

```
var elements = selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery('image');
elements.each(function(i) {
    result[i] = $(this).attr('xlink:href');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is that happening? Because `this` isn't what you think it is (or want it to be) in the scope of that function. Without knowing the exact context, `this` may point to the window, or another element, or an instance of an object.

You have a list of images stored in your `elements` array, and you want to create a jQuery object containing the image stored at index `i` of that array, so use `$(elements[i])` rather than `$(this)`.

I expect what happened is that after your initial failed attempt at using `$.each()`, you modified it to the standard Javascript `for` loop but left the (now incorrect) use of `this` to refer to the current element in the iteration.